# What is the equivalent of `npm install` for `gradle`?

Tags: docker, gradle

Is there an equivalent of `npm install` for Gradle?

I wanted to cache layers of my Gradle build.  Normally if it was an npm project I would do this

```
FROM node
COPY package.json package-lock.json .
RUN npm install # at this point the dependencies are downloaded
COPY src/ src/
RUN npm run build
```

So I am trying to do it the same way but with Gradle

```
FROM gradle:jdk12 AS build
COPY *.gradle .
RUN ????
COPY src/ src/
RUN gradle build
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as I see you are insterested in caching gradle depenencies in you docker image. You can use `gradle dependencies` to list dependencies and as side effect dependenices will be downloaded (you have to have `build.gradle` file already copied to the image) :

```
RUN gradle dependencies
```

or with gradle wrapper :

```
RUN ./gradlew dependencies
```

Also to force refreshing dependencies you could use `--refresh-dependencies` :

```
RUN gradle dependencies --refresh-dependencies
```